# how to use lampp server for django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, ubuntu, lampp

i want to use lampp localhost for hosting my django mywebsite. and to create database for website in lampp in django
added this code in setting.py

DATABASES = {

```
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        #'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ''),        'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
        'USER': 'DB_USER',
        'PASSWORD': 'DB_PASSWORD',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to deploy the app locally to learn and understand process of deploying and don't want use the in built functionality which starts the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is an link from official Django docs on deployment which gives you information about deployment and things to do before deployment

- [Deploying Django - Official Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/)

Following are few links which provide step by step guidance for deploying Django apps using LAMP on different types of Linux

- [How To Set Up an Apache, MySQL, and Python (LAMP) Server Without Frameworks on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-apache-mysql-and-python-lamp-server-without-frameworks-on-ubuntu-14-04)
- [How To Serve Django Applications with Apache and mod_wsgi on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04)
- [How To Serve Django Applications with Apache and mod_wsgi on CentOS 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-centos-7)
- [How to Run a Django Site with Apache, mod_wsgi, and MySQL on FreeBSD 10.1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-a-django-site-with-apache-mod_wsgi-and-mysql-on-freebsd-10-1)

You should also Look into [pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) which is PaaS to deploy python based apps for free with limited usage.